# Python - Logistic regression using tensorflow- accuracy stuck at 50%

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, logistic-regression

So, as the title says I try to train my module but the accuracy I get stays the same.
**I can only Use TensorFlow Library**
My data-set labels are "male" and "female"
(trying to distinguish between male and female voices)

code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf


def prep_data(target_class=1, train_siz=120, test_siz=30):

    cols = ['meanfreq', 'sd', 'median', 'Q25', 'Q75', 'IQR', 'skew', 'kurt', 'sp.ent', 'sfm', 'mode', 'centroid',
            'meanfun', 'minfun', 'maxfun', 'meandom', 'mindom', 'maxdom', 'dfrange', 'modindx', 'label']

    iris_df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Owner\\PycharmProjects\\TesnsorFlowU\\voice.csv', header=None, names=cols)

    iris_df = iris_df.drop(iris_df.index[0])

    # Encode class
    class_name = ['male', 'female']
    iris_df['iclass'] = [class_name.index(class_str)
                         for class_str in iris_df['label'].values]

    # Random Shuffle before split to train/test
    orig = np.arange(len(iris_df))
    perm = np.copy(orig)
    np.random.shuffle(perm)
    iris = iris_df[
        ['meanfreq', 'sd', 'median', 'Q25', 'Q75', 'IQR', 'skew', 'kurt', 'sp.ent', 'sfm', 'mode', 'centroid',
         'meanfun', 'minfun', 'maxfun', 'meandom', 'mindom', 'maxdom', 'dfrange', 'modindx', 'iclass']].values
    iris[orig, :] = iris[perm, :]


    # Arrange Label value to consider one vs. all classification
    # ex. class 0 --> label 1.0, class 1 or 2 --> label 0.0
    if target_class in [1, 2]:
        target_class = target_class - 1  # python indexing rule
        for i in range(len(iris)):
            iclass = int(iris[i, -1])
            iris[i, -1] = float(iclass == target_class)
    else:
        print('Value Error (target_class)')

    # Split dataset
    trX = iris[:train_siz, :-1]
    teX = iris[train_siz:, :-1]
    trY = iris[:train_siz, -1]
    teY = iris[train_siz:, -1]

    return trX, trY, teX, teY


def linear_model(X, w, b):
    output = tf.matmul(X, w) + b

    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tr_x, tr_y, te_x, te_y = prep_data(target_class=3, train_siz=2218, test_siz=950)


    # Variables
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 20])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

    p5 = tf.constant(0.5)  # threshold of Logistic Regression

    w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([20, 1], mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))
    b = tf.Variable([0.])

    y_pred = linear_model(x, w, b)
    y_pred_sigmoid = tf.sigmoid(y_pred)  # for prediction
    #y_pred_sigmoid = tf.nn.relu(y_pred)

    #cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_pred_sigmoid))
    x_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_pred, logits=y_)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(x_entropy)

    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)
    delta = tf.abs((y_ - y_pred_sigmoid))
    correct_prediction = tf.cast(tf.less(delta, p5), tf.int32)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    # Train
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        print('Training...')

        for i in range(3001):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = tr_x, tr_y
            fd_train = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys.reshape((-1, 1))}
            train_step.run(fd_train)

            if i % 500 == 0:
                loss_step = loss.eval(fd_train)
                train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(fd_train)
                print('  step, loss, accurary = %6d: %8.3f,%8.3f' % (i, loss_step, train_accuracy))

                # Test trained model
        fd_test = {x: te_x, y_: te_y.reshape((-1, 1))}
        print('accuracy = %10.4f' % accuracy.eval(fd_test))
        conf_mat = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels=tf.argmax(y_, 1), predictions=tf.argmax(y_pred_sigmoid, 1), num_classes=2)
        te_y = te_y.reshape([950, 1])
        conf_mat_to_print = sess.run(conf_mat, feed_dict={x: te_x, y_: te_y})
        print(conf_mat_to_print)
```

Output:

```
Training...
  step, loss, accurary =      0:    1.156,   0.483
  step, loss, accurary =    500:  -94.210,   0.505
  step, loss, accurary =   1000: -189.574,   0.505
  step, loss, accurary =   1500: -284.936,   0.505
  step, loss, accurary =   2000: -380.298,   0.505
  step, loss, accurary =   2500: -475.661,   0.505
  step, loss, accurary =   3000: -571.024,   0.505

accuracy =     0.4874

conf_mat:
[[950   0]
 [  0   0]]
```

As you can see in the confusion matrix the module wrongly think all the training data comes from male...

I tried a lot of stuff, and I can not understand where I'm wrong.

Comment: Is your dataset balanced? Even if it is, when you split it into training and testing dataset they will no longer be balanced. You should look at reshuffling your training data every epoch as well ([this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/24539) is why).

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, please can you share sample data, so that we can help you. Thanks!